# Difference of start date time and end date time in mins

Tags: r, date, time

I am trying to find the difference of these two columns

```r
start time = 24-01-2021 19:15
end time = 24-01-2021 19:22
```

Code used:

```
difftime(database_1$end_time,database_1$start_time, units = "mins")
```

Real output = `0 mins`

Expected output = `7 mins`

Answer (score 0):

Use `as.POSIXct` to convert character string to date-time format :

```
start_time = "24-01-2021 19:15"
end_time = "24-01-2021 19:22"
difftime(end_time,start_time, units = "mins")
#> Time difference of 0 mins

start_time = as.POSIXct(start_time, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
end_time = as.POSIXct(end_time, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
difftime(end_time,start_time, units = "mins")
#> Time difference of 7 mins
```

Comment: okay i will try this, thanks